# The simplest billiards problem

Tags: geometry, vectors, dynamical-systems, billiards

**The Problem:**

> Let's say we have a rectangle of size $m \times n$ centered at the origin (or, if it makes the math easier, you can place it wherever on the plane). We take a billiard ball, represented by a point, in the center of the rectangle with a constant velocity vector $\vec{v}$. Assuming no other forces acting on the ball, write a function $f(m,n,t)$ that gives the position of the ball after $t$ seconds.

**My Work:**
I don't actually know all that much vector math (this is a junior high pre-calc class), so I tried to set this up as a geometry problem. With the constraints above, if we expand our velocity vector $\vec{v}=\langle a,b\rangle$, our problem is as shown:

[image]

Let's call the angle the vector makes with the x-axis $\theta$. Making a triangle with our vector and the x-axis, we get that $\tan(\theta)=\frac{b}{a}$. So, $\theta=\arctan(\frac{b}{a})$.

Now, if we want to find the vector pointing to where the ball is going to hit the boundary of the rectangle $\vec{h}$, we know it is going to be the same direction as $\vec{v}$, just a different magnitude. Mathematically put:
$$\frac{1}{||v||}\vec{v}=\frac{1}{||h||}\vec{h}$$

We can calculate the magnitude of $\vec{h}$ by noticing that $$\sin(\theta)=\sin(\arctan(\frac ba))=\frac{\frac{m}{2}}{||h||}$$
Which simplifies quite nicely to:
$$||h||=\frac{m \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{2 b}$$
Returning to our original equation, we can re-arrange to get that $\frac{||h||}{||v||}\vec{v}=\vec{h}$. Since the magnitude of $\vec{v}$ is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, this, astoundingly, simplifies to $\vec{h}=\frac{m}{2b}\vec{v}$, leading me to believe there was a *way* easier way to do what I did. So, we found the first point that the ball will "bounce" at. But I have no idea how to model the ball "reflecting" and then to calculate where it will bounce again and again.

This was extra credit on an exam, and I didn't have time for it during the exam but it still interests me. Any help?

Comment: The  collision will change the sign of 1 of the components of the velocity vector: if it hits the left or the right wall, it will change the $x$, and it will change the $y$ otherwise.

Comment: Notice that motion on a rectangular billiard is equivalent to motion on a torus.

Comment: One (non) cheat.  Imagine an infinite table.  Where does the ball end then.  Consider how many vertical tables it passed through.  Find out the x value mod table width.  If it passed through an number of tables take the negative of that.  Do the same for the vertical.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following: When the (straight-line) trajectory leaves through the top edge, $f(m,n,t)$ must reflect in the $y$ direction through the line $y=m/2$, and similarly when it passes through any of the other edges. That is, we may think of the straight-line trajectory $g(t)=[at,bt]$, and find $f(m,n,t)=[h_n(at),h_m(bt)],$ where $h_{k}(x)$ is a $2k$-periodic function always mapping into $[-k/2,k/2]$, linear on each segment, and such that for small $x,$ $h_{k}(k/2-x)=h_{k}(k/2+x)$, $h_{k}(-k/2-x)=h_{k}(-k/2+x)$. Then the function we need is given by $$h_{k}(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{if }-k/2<x\leq k/2,\\ k-x&\text{if }k/2<x\leq 3k/2,\end{cases}$$ and extended by $2k$-periodicity so that $h_{k}(x+2kn)=h_{k}(x)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

That is, $f(m,n,t)=[h_{n}(at),h_{m}(bt)]$ with $h_{k}$ defined for any $k>0$ as above. Note that it is just as easy to solve in the case that we start at some point $[c,d]$, because we have already dispensed with the "hard part," which are the reflections. Then in this case, we just have $f(m,n,t)=[h_{n}(c+at),h_{m}(d+bt)]$.

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

[image]

The pink ball is the one bouncing off the walls.  Now imagine a "ghost" green ball that can pass through walls but otherwise has the same speed and direction.